# What's the URL for a category archive?

Tags: categories, archives, urls

If my category URL is:

/blogs/category/foo

and my archive URL is:

/blogs/2011/02/

what's the URL for 'foo' blogs from February 2011?

Comment: /blogs/category/foo/?y=2011&monthnum=02

Comment: @t31os: If you move that to an answer we could expand it with rewrite rules, so it has nice urls!

Comment: Wouldn't any rules written for such a URL conflict with the sub-category rules though? I think that's why no such rules exist, how can you differentiate between a category URL that's date based, and one that's simply a sub-caegory URL. You're welcome to factor in my suggestion to your own answer if you like.

Comment: @t31os: Hmm, it should be possible... With a non-greedy regex, and because the date archive ends with digits. I'll think about it and maybe come back with a complete answer!

Comment: @t31os: I expanded my answer with rewrite rules that add date-based browsing. As I thought, the non-greedy rewrite rules make this possible.

Comment: Nicely done, seems to do the trick... :) +1

Comment: Try this: ?y=2016&monthnum=01&orderby=date&order=ASC This is just an example, change year and mon.

Answer (score 3):

There is no date-based archive for a category. The `/category/[slug]/` pages are already "archives", in that they display old posts over different pages.

The different pages can be accessed by adding `page/2/`, `page/3/`, ... to the URL. The template tags to add these links are [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and [`previous_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_posts_link).

If you want to add a date-based layer to your category archives, you can add a rewrite rule to match a year, optional month and optional paging.

```
add_filter( 'category_rewrite_rules', 'wpse8769_category_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse8769_category_rewrite_rules( $category_rules )
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    // This could be incorrect for fancy permastructs, only tested in simple situations
    $category_permastruct = str_replace( $wp_rewrite->rewritecode, $wp_rewrite->rewritereplace, $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() );
    $category_permastruct = preg_replace( '|^/+|', '', $category_permastruct );

    $category_extra_rules = array(
        // Or split this up over different rewrite rules, if the regex is too complicated
        // Feeds are left as an exercise for the reader
        $category_permastruct . '/([0-9]{4})(/([0-9]{1,2}))?(/page/([0-9]+))?/?$' =>
            'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&year=$matches[2]&monthnum=$matches[4]&paged=$matches[6]',
    );

    return $category_extra_rules + $category_rules;
}
```

Comment: My /category/[slug]/ URL only displays the most recent 10 posts, with no links to any others. Is there a way I can paginate them?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q: what's the URL for 'foo' blogs from February 2011?**

The URL in the context of your site is: `/blogs/category/foo/?y=2011&monthnum=02`

(I blatantly copied this over from a commment t31os, so credits to him for this)

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't quite work. It limits the month to February OK, but the year filter doesn't take effect, so I end up with posts from Feb 2011, Feb 2010, etc.

Comment: ... and if I change it from "y=2011" to "year=2011", I get redirected to /blogs/2011/02/ thus losing the category